# How can zipWith be implemented with foldr?

Tags: haskell

I am learning haskell and I need to define `zipWith` function using `foldr`.

I can do it using pattern matching and recursion, but that doesn't work for me at the moment.
For example:

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' f = go
    where
        go [] _ = []
        go _ [] = []
        go (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : go xs ys
```

I also understand how folds work, but I can't really think of how I can use them to define `zipWith`.

From already thank you very much.

Comment: Try implementing `map` using `foldr`. Next, consider `zipWith' f = map (uncurry f) (zip xs ys)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `zipWith'` using `foldr` like so:

```hs
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' f xs ys = fst $ foldr go ([], reverse xs) ys where
    go _ (res, []) = (res, [])
    go y (res, z:zs) = (f z y : res, zs)
```

Answer (score 2):

To use `foldr`, you need to rewrite your definition in an equivalent way so that it has this form:

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' f = go
    where
    go []     = someConstant
    go (x:xs) = someFunction x (go xs)
```

Indeed, that is equivalent to `zipWith' f = foldr someFunction someConstant`.

We need the second list argument, so let's add it as a lambda. The "constant" we met above is actually a function of the second list, since that's the only way to obtain the wanted type:

```
    go []     = \ _list -> []   -- first case complete
    go (x:xs) = \ list  ->
        somehowUse x (go xs) list
```

Now we can pattern match on `list`

```
    go []     = \ _list -> []   -- first case complete
    go (x:xs) = \ list  -> case list of
        []     -> ...
        (y:ys) -> ...
```

and now we can follow the original code.

Can you see how to proceed now?

Comment: I thank you for the effort, although the truth is that I cannot see it as you put it. I thought it would be easier

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to do a `foldr` on one of the lists, then this isn't too difficult and one of the other answers will help you.

However, if you want to use `foldr` on *both*, this is actually quite a difficult question, and one that was thought to not be possible for quite a while!

We can do it with the following bizarre type:

```hs
data Hyp a b = Hyp { invoke :: Hyp b a -> b }
```

This is the type of *hyperfunctions* from `a` to `b`. Here's how it can be used to zip:

```hs
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith c xs ys = invoke (foldr xf xb xs) (foldr yf yb ys)
  where
    xf x xk = Hyp (\yk -> invoke yk xk x)
    xb = Hyp (\_ -> [])

    yf y yk = Hyp (\xk x -> c x y : invoke xk yk)
    yb = Hyp (\_ _ -> [])
```

If you want to read more about the problem look [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.36.4961&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: This is a very interesting approach, but I believe it's quite hard to understand without a detailed discussion of the code. Right now, I can't even fully see what are the types of `xf,xb,yf,yb`.

Comment: @chi: Supposing `type To x y = Hyp (x -> y) y; type Fro x y = Hyp y (x -> y)`, the functions `xf` and `yf` accumulate a `To` & `Fro` respectively: `xf :: a -> To a [c] -> To a [c]`, `xb :: To a [c]`, `yf :: b -> Fro a [c] -> Fro a [c]`, `yb :: Fro a b`. The fold over `xs` = `[x0, x1, …]` makes a chain of applications `($ x0)`, `($ x1)`, … ending in `($ const [])`, the fold over `ys` = `[y0, y1, …]` makes a stream of continuations `\ k0 x0 -> f x0 y0 : k0 \ k1 x1 -> …` ending in `\ kN _ -> kN $ const []`, and one applied to the other is a stream that ping-pongs to & fro, zipping elements.